# Error in sysconf() in C++

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I am compiling a program which gives me the following error. The version of gcc is (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4.

```
Utils.cpp: In static member function ‘static double Utils::process_mem_usage()’:
Utils.cpp:33:30: error: ‘_SC_PAGE_SIZE’ was not declared in this scope
  long page_size_kb = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE) / 1024; // if x86-64 is configured to use 2MB pages
                              ^
Utils.cpp:33:43: error: ‘sysconf’ was not declared in this scope
  long page_size_kb = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE) / 1024; // if x86-64 is configured to use 2MB pages
```

Answer (score 4):

Include `<unistd.h>`, where `_SC_PAGE_SIZE` is defined and [`sysconf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sysconf.html) is declared.

See POSIX spec: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/unistd.h.html

Comment: Thanks !! I am so dumb no to notice that missing header file :P

Comment: Haha. I can't remember the right headers either. I just plough through the man pages (or google) whenever this sort of error hits me :)